# Error in setting Hibernate Configuration

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, hibernate-mapping

I am getting error coming in to configure hibernate for postgresql database -

[image]

**Error Log Details -**

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: could not instantiate RegionFactory [org.hibernate.cache.impl.bridge.RegionFactoryCacheProviderBridge]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.createRegionFactory(SettingsFactory.java:402)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:270)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2163)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2159)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1383)
    at org.hibernate.console.ConsoleConfiguration$5.execute(ConsoleConfiguration.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.console.execution.DefaultExecutionContext.execute(DefaultExecutionContext.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.console.ConsoleConfiguration.execute(ConsoleConfiguration.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.console.ConsoleConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(ConsoleConfiguration.java:273)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.LazySessionFactoryAdapter.getChildren(LazySessionFactoryAdapter.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.BasicWorkbenchAdapter.getChildren(BasicWorkbenchAdapter.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.BasicWorkbenchAdapter.fetchDeferredChildren(BasicWorkbenchAdapter.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.ui.progress.DeferredTreeContentManager$1.run(DeferredTreeContentManager.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.createRegionFactory(SettingsFactory.java:397)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.cache.CacheException: could not instantiate CacheProvider [org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider]
    at org.hibernate.cache.impl.bridge.RegionFactoryCacheProviderBridge.<init>(RegionFactoryCacheProviderBridge.java:66)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider cannot be found by org.hibernate.eclipse.libs_3.7.1.Final-v20131205-0918-B107
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:191)
    at org.hibernate.util.ReflectHelper.classForName(ReflectHelper.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.cache.impl.bridge.RegionFactoryCacheProviderBridge.<init>(RegionFactoryCacheProviderBridge.java:63)
    ... 18 more
```

**UPDATE:**

After the changes mentioned by @ConMan, I am getting a new error at the same place -

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not instantiate dialect class
    at org.hibernate.dialect.resolver.DialectFactory.constructDialect(DialectFactory.java:163)
    at org.hibernate.dialect.resolver.DialectFactory.buildDialect(DialectFactory.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2163)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2155)
    at org.hibernate.console.ConsoleConfiguration$6.execute(ConsoleConfiguration.java:430)
    at org.hibernate.console.execution.DefaultExecutionContext.execute(DefaultExecutionContext.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.console.ConsoleConfiguration.execute(ConsoleConfiguration.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.console.ConsoleConfiguration.getSettings(ConsoleConfiguration.java:428)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter$2.execute(LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.console.execution.DefaultExecutionContext.execute(DefaultExecutionContext.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.console.ConsoleConfiguration.execute(ConsoleConfiguration.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter.readDatabaseSchema(LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter.getChildren(LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.BasicWorkbenchAdapter.fetchDeferredChildren(BasicWorkbenchAdapter.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.ui.progress.DeferredTreeContentManager$1.run(DeferredTreeContentManager.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect cannot be cast to org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect
    at org.hibernate.dialect.resolver.DialectFactory.constructDialect(DialectFactory.java:157)
    ... 16 more
```

Comment: Which Hibernate version are you using? Are you also using Spring?

Comment: I am using hibernate-core 4.3.0.Final as a maven dependency in project. My parent project is having Spring dependency as well.

Comment: Is this just error on IDEs hibernate view or does it come also when you run the code?  Check the project classpath on IDE that its same as on Maven.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider cannot be found by org.hibernate.eclipse.libs_3.7.1.Final-v20131205-0918-B107
```

This basically means that the implementation of hibernate you are using (org.hibernate.eclipse.libs...) does not contain the class NoCacheProvider.class.

An implementation of the NoCacheProvider can be found in the following dependencies:

- hibernate-core - 3.6.0.Final, 3.5.0-Final, 3.3.0.SP1, 3.3.0.GA
- com.springsource.org.hibernate - 3.3.2, 3.3.1, 3.2.6
- hibernate-core - 3.6.10.Final-patched-play-1.2.5, 3.6.1.Final-patched-play-1.2, 3.5.6-Final-patched-play-1.1.1, 3.5.6-Final-patched-play-1.1
- hibernate - 3.2.7.ga, 3.2.6.ga, 3.2.5.ga, 3.2.4.sp1, 3.2.4.ga,
  3.2.3.ga, 3.2.2.ga, 3.2.1.ga, 3.2.0.ga, 3.2.0.cr3, 3.2.0.cr2, 3.2.0.cr1, 3.1.3, 3.1.2, 3.1.1, 3.1
- hibernate - 3.1beta3, 3.1beta2, 3.1beta1, 3.0.5, 3.0.3
- hibernate-all - beta3.SP15

Source: [Grep Code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org$maven2@org.hibernate$hibernate-core@4.0.0.Beta1@org$hibernate$cache$NoCacheProvider)

**EDIT:**

I have just seen that you are using hibernate-core 4.3.0.Final.  It would appear that the NoCacheProvider class no longer exists in this version of hibernate.  The recommended alternative is to use the following class instead:

```
org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCachingRegionFactory
```

Comment: I changed the way you mentioned but the error is different now and rest all is same. See update in my question. It seems as if properties like `<property name="hibernate.default_schema">my_schema</property>` aren't the good place for `hibernate.cfg.xml` and are the source of such problems.

Comment: what value are you using for the property hibernate.dialect, and what type of database are you using?

Comment: I am using `<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>` and my database is PostgreSQL.

Comment: Are you using different versions of hibernate (i.e. between hibernate-core, hibernate-annotations, hibernate-search etc...), there could be a conflict between incompatible versions here?

Comment: I think you are pretty right. I just got this same feeling of version difference and so going with dependency `hibernate-entitymanager` that takes care of all. Let's see now what happens).